# Is there a warning in gcc for octal literals?

Tags: gcc, warnings, octal

ie. so that if you use any octal literals it give you a warning.

Same question for Microsoft's compiler.

If not are there any other tools to detect octal literals.

(vim seems to have a cool trick where it highlights the first leading
zero a different color, but I'm thinking more of an automated tool).

Comment: `ack '(?<=\D)0[0-7]+' file.c` will only have a few (if any) false positives in comments and strings, and will be more flexible (if not always better) than any other tool you use for this. (If you don't have `ack`, fix that.)

Comment: Looking at it, the lookbehind should be `(?<=\W)` (or `\b` (I think) would probably work just as well).

Comment: ack is totally awesome. I have perl compiled for an embeded linux just so I can use ack on it

Comment: I guess I should've put that as an answer.

Comment: @ChrisLutz: this matches all floats within [0..1[, as well as (but it may be a very special case) all clock values with minutes less than 10 (12:03).

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe gcc has such a warning.  I just ran `info gcc` (for gcc 4.5.2) and searched for "octal".  There were only two occurrences, neither of them useful.

I don't know about Microsoft's compiler.

You could search your source files for a regular expression that matches octal constants.  If you have `grep`, something like this should do the trick (warning: I haven't tested this):

```
grep '\<0[0-7][0-7]*' foo.c
```

This matches a 0 followed by one or more digits in the range 0..7, at the beginning of a word.  It deliberately does not match `0`, which is an octal constant but presumably not one you're worried about.  It's likely to give you some false positives, for example in string literals and comments.  It will also match a character constant like `'\007'`, which is octal but not as error-prone as an octal integer constant.

Comment: I didn't know plain `grep` had `\<`.

Comment: Also, wouldn't `[0-7]+` (or `[0-7]\{1,\}` if plan `grep` doesn't support `+`) be more concise?

Answer (score 1):

(Question is tagged gcc, but text asks about Microsoft's compiler as well.)

I don't think MSVC++ has a warning for general octal literals, but it will warn about suspicious octal escape sequences in string literals.  For example `"foo \669"`, will trigger "[C4125 decimal digit terminates octal escape sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6247ac1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)" if you have the warning level turned all the way up.